# rotate a photo using css and avoid the appearance of margins

Tags: html, css, image, rotation, photo

in an html page I load a variable number of photos with 16/9 format,
by pressing a button I would like to rotate the photos by 90 degrees, applying the CSS tranform rotate I get the rotation of the same but a border is added to the photos, how can I avoid it?
the photos are inserted in this way

```
<img src = "foto1.jpg" style = "width: 100%; height: auto;">
<div style = "display: block; width: 100vw; height: 5px; background-color: yellow"> </div>
<img src = "foto2.jpg" style = "width: 100%; height: auto;"> <div style = "display: block; width: 100vw; height: 5px; background-color: yellow"> </ div >
```

the CSS I use for rotation is this

```
transform: rotate (90deg) translateY (-100%);
transform-origin: top left;
```

applied via js
the image is rotated correctly but a white space appears below it and the yellow line that should be in contact with the photo is spaced out, I have searched a lot but can't find the solution, it seems that everyone is just rotating square images

Comment: Hi! Ensure your image also has an alt attribute to either provide alt text or mark the image as decorative. You can learn more about alt text here: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/decision-tree/#:~:text=This%20decision%20tree%20describes%20how,instead%20of%20images%20of%20text.

Comment: Could you put a runnable snippet into your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with this. Note that when you transform an element you don't move the basic place it is occupying on the page.

Comment: hi the "alt" tag is not needed simply because it is a web page for me, not public

Comment: so transform is not the best way to rotate the photo, there is a way to change the place it is occupying on the page as well